# Which answer is right? I had a steady (job)?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, exam-questions

The question below is from my homework.

> I had a steady_____
>
> 1. Career
> 2. Job
> 3. Work
> 4. Profession

I searched on the internet and I found it difficult to get the answer.

I think **job** is correct, am I right?

Comment: OK, I'm reopening it. But please be aware that saying "I searched the internet" may not be sufficient in the future. It's better to explain what you know and include what you found, with a link to the source if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had a steady **job**.

A *job* is specific work done for a specific employer. *steady* means it did not change for some period of time. It would not be temporary work or work not expected to continue for some reason.

*career* and *profession* are a more long term, possibly lifetime reference to the type of work you do, such as a doctor, lawyer or software engineer. You may have many jobs in your lifetime, but these change less often or not at all.

*work* is incorrect. While the meaning may be OK (though very generalized), it would need to be:

> I had steady work.

*work* is non-count so no article is used.

And of course none of them should be capitalized in your context.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I don’t think we could call _steady career_ “incorrect.” _She had a steady career as a government clerk before retiring in 2016_. It’s just that _steady job_ is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+steady+job%2C+a+steady+career&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15) idiomatically. I feel like “I had a steady career” may be true, but, by itself, it begs for more context and explanation, whereas “I had a steady job” speaks for itself and stands on its own.